# Keen eye for detail (or details?)

Tags: idioms

Which one is correct? "To have a keen eye for *detail*" or "To have a keen eye for *details*"?

Comment: And why just one eye for that matter? Worth another question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem is that this is an idiom within an idiom.

A Google search turns up:

> **to have a keen eye for sth** synonym | English synonyms ...
>
> dictionary.reverso.

and, to give some examples from the internet,

> ... have a keen eye for pigments and dyes
>
> ... have a keen eye for "fabricated" essays
>
> ... have a keen eye for details.

but I can't seem to access the promised dictionary.reverso entry.

So 'have a keen eye for' accepts count nouns. 'Have a keen eye for a bargain' is an idiom within an idiom and apparently count.

**Have a keen eye for detail** is a longer set expression, and obviously uses the non-count version of 'detail'. However, this does nor indicate that 'have a keen eye for details' is in any way wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The former option is my best bet.  A Google search showed that "a keen eye for detail" is 9 times more prevalent than the alternative.

Comment: I know, but I've just found the second option in a magazine article.
I was wondering if it's correct as well.